# How to send client data of a random song from large playlist?

Tags: php, algorithm, node.js

I created an API that returns data about a song on my server, including the stream URL.  When a client calls the API, it'll get the data, and start streaming the song in their player.

But now that I have multiple clients making the call to the API, what is the best way to return data about a **random** song in the playlist that they haven't heard recently?  There are a couple thousand of song and still expanding.

So my **question** is the whether the following is a good approach:

Here is what I am planning on doing.  Set up sessions for each client, and on the initial request, I take all the songs, generate a random list, save it in a cache along with their session ID, then on every subsequent request, I check their session ID, and grab and return the next song data?

As for making sure of not playing a recently played song, I'll have a history of the previous 50 songs listened to in a database, and do a song ID comparison, and fetch the next song if matched?

Would this be a working approach?

Comment: Can you use JavaScript Ajax to get the song data?

Comment: Yeah, but the method to call the API isn't the issue, but rather how to randomize the song list on the backend to send a random one in the API response.  Sorry if my question wasn't clear.

Comment: Let me know if my answer is what you're looking for. Please also edit your question to improve it.

Comment: My exact question wasn't the previous comment I made.  The exact question is whether using sessions and storing a randomized playlist for each client in the cache, then serving it from that cache (session store) is a good approach.  Not the actual code on how to create a random playlist.  I rephrased some parts of my question to make it a bit clearer.

Comment: Okay; I changed my answer.

Answer (score 0):

**EDITED:** Got more info of the server.

Store X amount of songs in user's listening history (buffer, size X). Implement a single function for requesting a random song. When client requires a new random song:

1. pick a random song from your database
2. push the song ID to the listening history buffer.
3. return the data to client

There's actually no need to maintain a random generated song list if you are planning to store user data on the server anyways.

Otherwise, you're pretty much on point. Use sessions to identify a user.

Comment: I was thinking this too, but the constraint would be that I would have thousands of songs to randomize for a user.  I didn't think it would be good to blast out a list of a thousand random songs to every client.

Comment: Depending on the users of course, but: I would go with the one song at a time solution. Give the client one song at a time. When the client requests a new random song, you look at the previously listened song IDs from the HTTP request. Though getting a new song for the user gets slower based on how many songs the user has already listened to.

Comment: If you want the randomization work well, you will basically end up saving user accounts on your server side. This solution is also viable, but as I said it depends on your APIs users.

Comment: Right. I should have specified that listening history and activity **will** be stored server side. And the history to compare off of will be 50 songs or so, not a large number.  That being said, how do you think I should modify what I have in mind?

Comment: OK good. In this case: just store X (50 is OK) amount of songs in the listening history of the user. I would return only 1 song per client request. When you return it, you add the song to to the user's listening history (and remove the oldest entry from history keeping the list size at X). You only have to maintain one list, the user's listening history on the server. The client is also easier to implement with no list management.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using a database like mysql, or anything that associates and ID with a song, you can generate a random number and use that to select a random song from the database. Any ID based data store would work for this and would scale extremely well.

If you know your highest song ID is X, then generate a random number between 1 and X, call it Y. The perform a query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM songs WHERE song_id>=Y LIMIT 1
```

That will allow for gaps in your ID and will be really fast. You could keep a log of the songs played in another table and filter those out. If the query returns no results, then invert the random number like Y = X-Y, and then run the query again.